# Is this the right place to ask about tuning a TV?

Tags: support, scope

Is this the right place to ask about tuning a TV?

I was looking through the StackExchange sites and really don't know where I should post this. I'm aware that this site is for TV series so if anyone can recommend a better place then comment.

Comment: Tuning,  how? If you are asking am in depth question about tv electronics, Electrical Engineering, About the rf maybe ham or physics stack. For EE, basic questions may not get well received.

Answer (score 5):

**No, it is not.** Referring to the [corresponding section in the help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:**
>
> - Technology questions about playing content

Unfortunately, though, *as to my knowledge* there doesn't seem to be any other SE site where this question would be on-topic either. But you could ask on the [main meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), where there is specifically a tag [`site-recommendation`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) for finding the appropriate site for a question.